# How to create objects in R with "unknown name"?

Tags: r, object

I am trying to create (vector) objects in `R`. Thereby, I want to achieve that I don't specify *a priori* the name of the object. For example if I have a list of length 3, I want to create the objects `p1` to `p3` and if I have a list of length 10, the objects `p1`to `p10` have to be created. The length should be arbitrary and not *a priori* determined.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the proper way of doing that is to consider a list `p = list()` and then you can use `p[[i]]` with `i` as big as you wish without having specified any length.

Then once your list is filled up, you can rename it: `names(p) = paste0("p",c(1:length(p)))`

Finally, if you want to get all the `pi` variables directly accessible, you add `attach(p)`

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about this, but I wish to use the variables in later analysis as predictors in the `glm` function which makes it a bit difficult. I need this for step-wise model building.

Comment: if all the vectors are to be of equal length `l`, why  don't you use a matrix : `mat = matrix(nrow = l)` and then fill it with `cbind`. Finally, use `as.data.frame` and each column would have a name `Vi`

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hack but you can do the following

```
short_list <- list(rnorm(10),rnorm(20),1:3)
long_list <- c(short_list,short_list )

paste0("p",seq_along(short_list))

mapply(assign, paste0("p",seq_along(short_list)), short_list, MoreArgs = list(envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

result:

```
> p3
[1] 1 2 3
```

you can do the same with `long_list`

I dont see a statistical model you will need this. Better start working with *lists* like `short_list` or *data.frame*'s directly.

**PS** If you just want to use it for glm you probably want to learn `formula`'s in **R**.
`glm(y~., data=your_data)` takes all columns in your data-frame that are not named *y* as regressor. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Thanks with the comment on `glm`. The trick with the `data.frame` helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`assign` (and maybe also `attach`) are often a sign that you have not yet arrived at an "Rish" version of the code.

Considering that you need this for modeling: if your $p_1 \cdot p_n$ are of the same type, you can put them into a matrix (inside a column of a `data.frame`; for modeling they anyways need to be of same length):

```
df$matrix <- p.matrix
```

If you directly create the `data.frame`, you need to make sure the matrix is not expanded to data.frame columns:

```
df <- data.frame (matrix = I (matrix), ...)
```

Then `glm (y ~ matrix, ...)`  will work.

For examples of this technique see e.g. packages `pls` or `hyperSpec` or the [`pls` paper in the Journal of Statistical Software](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v18/i02).